# Google App Engine - Static IP address (Custom Domain)

Tags: google-app-engine, https, google-cloud-platform, ip-address

I have a question regarding **IP Address** in *Google App Engine*. I know there is no way to have a static IP-address, but my client have setup a `Custom Domain` with some IP-address showing up. My problem is:

There is an endpoint(API) that they are connected on, the problem is that the destination requires **IP-address** and **PORT** to open in their firewall-policy. Since there is no *"Static IP"* on Google App Engine, can i use those IP-address showing under `"data"` in Google App Engine in `Custom Domains`?

Because when i enter the domain in my web-browser i see the same IP listed in Custom Domain. Can i send over those IP-addresses than the Pool of IP by running: `nslookup -q=TXT _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com 8.8.8.8`Because those domain listed in nslookup is not shown in the network (remote address)

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The result of running `nslookup -q=TXT _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com 8.8.8.8` is not static. Google may introduce `new _cloud-netblocks` entries at any time.

In the Google Cloud documentation section [Static IP Addresses and App Engine apps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip) is the recommended approach to retrieve the IPs. You will have to run:

```
nslookup -q=TXT _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com 8.8.8.8
```

And then, from the response , you'll have to query each of the `_cloud-netblocksN` listed. Let take this query response as an example:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
_cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com  text = "v=spf1 include:_cloud-netblocks1.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks2.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks3.googleusercontent.com ?all
```

There's 3 `_cloud-netblocksN` listed, so you'll have to query them:

```
nslookup -q=TXT _cloud-netblocks1.googleusercontent.com 8.8.8.8
nslookup -q=TXT _cloud-netblocks2.googleusercontent.com 8.8.8.8
nslookup -q=TXT _cloud-netblocks3.googleusercontent.com 8.8.8.8
```

The SPF records returned from the query of each of those above entries will be IP ranges that you can use for App Engine.

Comment: I know that @Guillermo. My question was regaarding the Custom Domain. There is no static IP-address in App Engine.

Comment: Any one? Maby use a proxy but i do not know how

Answer (score 0):

The static IP address for AppEngine is now* possible using serverless NEG with Load Balancer.

- See more on https://stackoverflow.com/a/62660953/4185100

Using this method, it is also possible to configure multiple domains/sub-domains with HTTPS load balancer which points to internal serverless resources (different AppEngine services, Cloud functions, etc)